# How do you align the label

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I align the "remember me" box so that it comes to left side so that the checkbox should start with username and password text boxes start.

Current it is -

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="buttons">
        <label>
            <input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" value="remember" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Remember me</label>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Fiddle your code please

Comment: We need to see some css

Comment: Include complete code (HTML and CSS) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: try adding `vertical-align:middle` to all of the elements in that row (so label and input)

Comment: Sorry- I feel so stupid - I have got it working now. Thanks everyone, I will remember to post everything clearly next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a label around your "Remember Me" text and assign a class to it;

Then give that class the following style:

```css
.aux {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="buttons">
        <label>
            <input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" value="remember" type="checkbox" />
            <label class="aux">&nbsp;Remember me</label>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is this you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, adding float attrib works !  thanks. Although I feel little embarrassed about this stupid question and not giving all css info at all. Ok I am applying "Ostrich_algorithm" to deal with this embarrassment now.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to remove margin for checkbox which is given by default

check for the first

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/bc2bcaf7/1/)

```
.valign{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

input{
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to insert your form in a two columns table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User Name:</td>
    <td><Input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><Input type="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="buttons">
        <label><input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" value="remember" type="checkbox" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wj86k32/

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr><td class="buttons"><label>Username</label></td>
    <td><input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" type="text" /></td></tr>

 <tr><td class="buttons"><label>Username</label></td>
     <td><input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" type="text" /></td></tr>

   <tr><td class="buttons"></td>
       <td><input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" /><label>remember me</label><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>
```

Is it your need ?